# Is okay to include elements other than list items in HTML lists?

Tags: html, html-lists

I don't know which is a right way to write:

```
<ol><li>something</li><div>something</div><li>something</li></ol>
```

or

```
 <ol><li>something<div>something</div></li><li>something</li></ol>
```

I have to add a div tag and a image tag between two lists. Well I am getting the output with both code above. But I wonder which is the correct one?

Comment: use the second one, it's a better structure. try using span instead of div aswell.

Comment: You'll want to get familiar with MDN and its [element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). See the Permitted Content section.

Comment: Browsers will attempt to correctly interpret invalid markup, but results can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A div **may** be a child element of a li.
- A div may **not** be a child element of an ol. Only li elements may be children of an ol.

So the second one is correct and the first is simply invalid.